# How map mongodb on ruby and rails

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

I am practice on ruby on rails 4 and using mongodb database,I am trying to work follow this site to connect database : http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html
However, when I worked this step this occur error:

```
rails g mongoid:config
```

error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    activemodel (4.1.1)

  In Gemfile:
    mongoid (~> 3.1.6) x86-mingw32 depends on
      activemodel (~> 3.2) x86-mingw32

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

I am also try the command `bundel update` but it has that error:

sorry I am new bie on ruby and rails and mongodb, so I hope there is any easy guide to follow.

thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try skipping ActiveRecord when creating your app.

```
rails new my_app -O
```

I had this problem using the following:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'mongoid', '~> 4.0.0'
```

Skipping ActiveRecord solved that error.

Comment: I changed the example. Thanks.